# JAXB Custom Binding for Untyped Element?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, jaxb

I have a very large and complex XSD for a SOAP service which I do not control.  There are several elements which always contain string data which are not typed. Typically these are very deeply-nested elements.

For example

```
...
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="foo"/>
          <xs:element name="bar"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
...
```

Is there a way to tell JAXB to always bind untyped elements (such as `foo` and `bar` above) to `java.lang.String`?

I understand that I can call out these exceptions individually using an XPath query string, but is there a one liner for this?

Comment: How complete is the XPath implementation used by binding files?  Would it be able to handle an expression like `//xs:element[not(@type)][not(xs:simpleType)][not(xs:complexType)]`

Comment: Write that up as an answer, please.  I think that'll work for a XJB custom binding node path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an external binding file an XPath expression like

```
//xs:element[not(@type)][not(xs:simpleType)][not(xs:complexType)]
```

would match any such element (assuming XJC has full XPath support rather than just a subset of the language).